# Ocultar menu en Angular 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular7

estoy teniendo problemas para ocultar mi menú quiero que al hacer click el menú se oculte o se queden los fa fa icons pero más pequeño como en la siguiente captura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como lo tengo actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código html es el siguiente:

```
    <header id="header">
  <div class="nav-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="navbar-brand-full" src="assets/images/logo-top.png" alt="Fundacion Hogar Renacer"/>
    </a>
    <span id="menu-toggle" class="collapse-sidebar">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="30" height="30" focusable="false"><title>Menu</title><path stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22"></path></svg>
    </span>
    <div class="menu-items"></div>
  </div>
</header><!-- /header -->

  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
    <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-heading"><img alt="Logo" src="assets/images/logo.png"/> </div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <a [routerLink]="['/home']" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="menu fas fa-home"></i> Inicio</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/citas']" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="menu fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Citas</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/pacientes']" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="menu fas fa-address-book"></i> Pacientes</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/personal']" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="menu fas fa-user-md"></i> Personal</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/contactos']" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="menu fas fa-binoculars"></i> Otros contactos</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/grupos']" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="menu fas fa-user"></i> Grupos</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/sesionesgrupos']" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="menu fas fa-users"></i> Sesiones en grupos</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/historial']" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="menu fas fa-book-medical"></i> Historia clinica</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/informes']" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="menu fas fa-clipboard-list"></i> Informes</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/documentos']" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light"><i class="menu fas fa-file-pdf"></i> Documentos</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">                   
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- <div class="header-title"> -->
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

En la etiqueta  con id="menu-toggle" es donde está el botón que al hacer click quiero que oculte el menú de navegacón

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Has probado un ngif?

Comment: Y el codigo ts? Ahi practicamente solo hay vanilla HTML y ni siquiera un listener for click o un ngif. Por favor aporta mas informacion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final lo resolví con lo siguiente:

```
document.getElementById('sidebar-wrapper').style.width = '240px';
```

Y para quitar el texto use *ngIf